# ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero

Tags: python, python-2.7, matemática

O código:

```
janela=[]
    for i in range(100):
        if(len(leitura)%i == 0):
            janela.append(i)
```

O erro que recebo é esse:

> ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero

Comment: O valor de `i` começa em zero por causa do `range` e você está tentando calcular o resto de divisão de algo por zero, o que não faz sentido. É importante cuidar sempre a indentação, pois no Python isso faz total diferença; no seu código a segunda linha não deveria estar indentada em relação a primeira. Para corrigir realmente o código será necessário que você explique o que ele deveria fazer e qual é o resultado esperado. Provavelmente você nem deveria estar utilizando Python 2 também, veja para migrar para o 3.

Comment: Foi isso mesmo. A questão da indentação foi quando passei o código pra cá, mas ele tá indentado correto. Obrigado!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como o nome diz a função `range()` gera números dentro uma faixa definida. Se você colocar apenas um número este será o limite final, e o começo será automaticamente 0, aí você faz uma divisão por esse primeiro número que ele gera e a matemática proíbe isto por não ter como definir o que seria esse resultado. Se colocar o início em 1 resolve o problema:

```
janela=[]
leitura = ""
for i in range(1, 100):
    if len(leitura) % i == 0:
        janela.append(i)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/VDi9z5). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/RangeStarting). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/RangeStarting.py).

Comment: Entendi, pura falta de atenção minha, obrigado!